# Enlazar un checkboxlist a un datagridview

Tags: c#, sql-server

Quisiera solicitar su apoyo para seleccionar algunos items de mi datagridview al seleccionar una opción en el checkedlistbox. Ejemplo si selecciono la opcion 2 solo deben marcarse en el grid las 3 ultimas opciones.  Solo logro que se seleccione todo pero quiero establecer por indice de fila que es lo que se selecciona en el grid. Este es mi formulario: 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

estoy utilizando leguaje c# en visual studio 2015 y sql server 2016.. 
Este es mi codigo del formulario:

```
    namespace CapaPresentacion
   {
    public partial class FrmCombos : Form
   {
    public FrmCombos()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    double Precio = 0;

    private void dataServicio_CellContentClick(object sender, 
    DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if (dataServicio.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value.ToString() == "1")
        {
            dataServicio.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value = "0";
        }
        else
        {
            dataServicio.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value = "1";
        }
    }

    //metodo ocultar columnas
    private void OcultarColumnas()
    {
        this.dataServicio.Columns[4].Visible = false;
    }

    private void dataServicio_CellValueChanged(object sender, 
    DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if (dataServicio.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "Seleccionarse")
        {
            DataGridViewRow row = dataServicio.Rows[e.RowIndex];

            DataGridViewCheckBoxCell cellSeleccion = row.Cells["Seleccionarse"] as DataGridViewCheckBoxCell;
        }
    }

    private void dataServicio_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (dataServicio.IsCurrentCellDirty)
        {
            dataServicio.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit);
        }
    }

    private void FrmCombos_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // TODO: esta línea de código carga datos en la tabla 'dsPrincipal.spcombo_venta' Puede moverla o quitarla según sea necesario.
        this.spcombo_ventaTableAdapter.Fill(this.dsPrincipal.spcombo_venta);
        this.OcultarColumnas();
    }

    private void chkKits_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataServicio.Rows)
        {
          row.Cells[Seleccionarse.Name].Value = true;
          Precio += Convert.ToDouble(row.Cells[3].Value);
        }

        txtTotal.Text = Convert.ToString(Precio);
        txtTotal.Text = (double.Parse(txtTotal.Text)).ToString("#,#.00");
    }
  }
}
```

Gracias de antemano!!!

Comment: Hola Jorge, tu pregunta está marcada para cierre por ser __demasiado amplia__. Edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico, con el suficiente nivel de detalle para permitir identificar una respuesta adecuada. Evita preguntar varias cosas distintas a la vez. Te recomiendo que incluyas un __[mcve]__ de lo que estás haciendo para solucionar tu problema.

Comment: Que tal.. entiendo ... soy nuevo en el foro.. ya edite la pregunta y la resumi con detalle.. Espero me apoyen con sus respuestas.. Gracias

Answer (score 0):

SOlo el primer item del listbox debe "checkear" todos los items del grid?
si es asi podrias intentar algo como esto en el evento `click` del `CheckListBox`:

```
... 
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
    row.Cells[CheckBoxColumn1.Name].Value = true;
}
...
```

eso se lo agregarias al primer item de tu checkListBox validando el indice del item:

```
foreach(int indexChecked in checkedListBox1.CheckedIndices) {
    if (indexChecked = 0) {
       foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
       {
          row.Cells[CheckBoxColumn1.Name].Value = true;
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Gracias Luis, el primero si selecciona todo, pero hay otros que no.. como le podria para especificar que fila quiero q marque y si las marca que las sume y si la desmarco que la reste...